# In the context of using ContentBox CMS, where does cb.siteBaseURL get the base url from?

Tags: coldfusion, lucee, coldbox, commandbox

[image: ContentBox Base URL]

I am running ContentBox on Lucee using CommandBox.  In my ContentBox Admin, when I first set it up, I had it running on 127.0.0.1.  Later, I created a web.config and updated the host file to use mydomain.com (I am using mydomain.com here as an example.  The actual domain name is different).  I have restarted the server a few times and even re-initiated a few times.  However, cb.siteBaseURL keeps returning 127.0.0.1.  My question is, where is cb.siteBaseURL getting the URL from?  While I might have overlooked, but I have looked at every field in both Settings and Geek Settings and I don't see anything that have to do with the base URL.

NOTE: I wish I could tag ContentBox.  However, it does not currently have a ContentBox tag.  To create a new tag, I need 1500 reputation, which I don't have.  So, Lucee, CommandBox, and ColdBox are the best ones I can come up with

Answer (score 2):

First of all, we have a dedicated community forum for ContentBox here: https://community.ortussolutions.com/c/communities/contentbox/15

The issue you are experiencing is because ContentBox is multi-site. So each potential host needs to be mapped to the domain in question.  Each site has a base url that you must define in order to build links and execute things.  So when you install ContentBox, we have no clue which domain you will attach it to, so it defaults to the 127 ip address.

So now that you have a domain, just go to the `Sites` and update the base url to your domain.